# Putting DOM queries in variable in J-Query Mobile works partially, changing the prop value doesn't work

Tags: jquery-mobile, dom, knockout.js

Library used.

knockout-2.2.0.js

jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js

I tried to put these DOM queries in a variable and used it.

Like this :

```
var $merchantCustomSelectVar = $('#idMerchantCustomSelect');
$merchantCustomSelectVar.live("change", function (event)
$merchantCustomSelectVar.prop('selectedIndex', self.lastSelected);
```

I observed as follows :

1# When I am binding to some event like "2-->" above it works good.

2# When I try to mutate some prop like "3-->" above  it doesn't works here though it works for the web applications.

Currently I am using jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js
I also tried with jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js and jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js but that didn't make any difference.

I tried these version of js as  while I was testing on JSFiddle there is was working good for "prop" manipulation, but the same don't work in the application.

jsfiddle.net/CWvwn/2101/

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: you mean this? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/CWvwn/2105/

Comment: Yes But here jsfiddle.net/CWvwn/2101/ it's working using variable $test but in j-query mobile same is not working.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/CWvwn/2114/ what doesn't work exactly?

Comment: var $test = $('#idSelect');
$test.prop('selectedIndex', 4);
self.lastSelected = $test.prop('selectedIndex');
alert(self.lastSelected); i am not able the use like this way using variable like $test variable. I have to use $('#idSelect') for changing the prop value in J-Query Mobile. Hope now it makes sense to you ??